# send video via url in telegram bot without saving it on server

Tags: python, automation, python-requests, bots, telegram-bot

I've created a bot that accepts a TikTok video link and in response sends this video to the user, downloaded from a third-party site. The problem I've encountered is that the video that should be sent to the user is saved on the server. Is it possible to make it so that the user can receive video without saving it on server?

i try to put link that third-part site create to download video to the script but it says
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

```
video_link = downloadVideo(video_url, 'index') 
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video=open(video_link, 'rb'))
```

main idea of def downloadVideo(link, id) is create link and download it to .mp4 file in case above I changed end of the code to return that link
the working code in which it saves video this:

```
def downloadVideo(link, id)
...
downloadSoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    downloadLink = downloadSoup.a["href"]
    mp4File = urlopen(downloadLink)
    with open(f"{id}.mp4", "wb") as output:
        while True:
           data = mp4File.read(4096)
           if data:
              output.write(data)
           else:
              break

downloadVideo(video_url, 'index')
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video=open(f'index.mp4', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The open() function is used to open the file saved on the device. When you pass video_url to open() function , it try to open file with that name, which is not in server. So its retun File Not Found error.

So, to solve your problem you can just write the video url in place of opening it.

```
video_link = downloadVideo(video_url, 'index') 
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video=video_link )
```

Hope this will help you.

*PS : This is my first stack overflow answer*